# Wattage calculation for resistors in series

Tags: resistors, resistance, watts, power-dissipation

I need the formula for calculating resistor wattage when the resistors are in series.  For example, say I have 3 1/4 watt 10 ohm resistors in series.  What is the potential power dissipation for the entire circuit?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since resistors are in series, the current will be the same throughout the chain. Assuming that the voltage V across the string of resistors is constant, you can calculate the current \$I={V \over R_1+R_2 +R_3+ ...}\$. Power dissipated on each of the resistors: \$P_i=I^2R_i\$. If \$P_i\$ is less than the power rating of the resistor, it should dissipate the power without burning.

A string of N identical resistors in series each rated for P watts can dissipate \$NP\$ watts.

Comment: Nice and simple.  Great explanation!

Comment: Twinkle, twinkle little star, power = i^2 r :-)

Comment: Nice...  I don't think I'll be forgetting that one any time soon.  =)

Comment: A uniform series or parallel string of *identical* resistors can dissipate NP watts.  The word *identical* is important, though.  Each resistor's contribution to dissipation will be proportional to its resistance, so a 1K 1W in series with a 2K 1W would only dissipate 1½W total (though one could use 1K ½W in series with a 2K 1W and get total power dissipation equal to the sum of the individual ones).

Comment: This simple formula is valid when the distance between the resistors is not too small. But a very close packaging of a lot of resistors may be very hot without derating.